# React parsing an array of objects coming from an API

Tags: reactjs

I'm quite new with react, I'm trying to hit an API and I'm getting this response. I need to go over the array and show the elements in a table:

```
{
  "people": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "philip",
      "age": 25,
      "timestamp": "2020-10-17T21:59:50.151"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "name": "philip2",
      "age": 26,
      "timestamp": "2020-10-17T21:59:50.152"
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "name": "philip3",
      "age": 27,
      "timestamp": "2020-10-17T21:59:50.153"
    },
  ]
}
```

I'm hitting and getting response from the api correctly but I have some issues trying to parse it.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import "./App.css";

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            people: []
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch('/local/api/people')
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(json => json.people)
            .then(people => this.setState({'people': people}))
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
            {this.state.people}
```

Here I'd need to go over the array and show all the elements

```
            </div>
    );
    }
}

export default App;


Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys ....... If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

I tried a lot of things but nothing worked so far

Comment: `this.state.people.map(...)`? This isn't parsing, fetch already did that for you when you called .json. See https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to map over the array inside the return like the code below and I am passing a key that's a react way to identify the element

> Keys help React identify which items have changed, are added, or are removed. Keys should be given to the elements inside the array to give the elements a stable identity:

and also am checking when the component renders that I will only show the list when the state people array length is true means not 0

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./App.css";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      people: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("/local/api/people")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((json) => json.people)
      .then((people) => this.setState({ people: people }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {this.state.people.length && this.state.people.map((element, key) => {
          return (
            <div key={key}>
              <span>{element.id}</span>
              <span>{element.name}</span>
              <span>{element.age}</span>
              <span>{element.timestamp}</span>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a member function that maps over the array and creates and returns jsx for each table row. You can then call this function inside a table body tag.

```
renderTableData() {
    return this.state.people.map((person, index) => {
      const { id, name, age } = person //destructuring
      return (
          <tr key={id}>
            <td>{id}</td>
            <td>{name}</td>
            <td>{age}</td>
          </tr>
      )
    })
  }

 render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
          <table id='people'>
            <tbody>
                {this.renderTableData()}
            </tbody>
          </table>
      </div>
    )
  }
```